# Error OracleAS and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have an application that use Spring and Hibernate.
Originally, I thought that this application would deployed on Tomcat, but, by requirements of customer, now I need deploy on Oracle AS 10g.
First,  appear me the famous error:

**XML-24509: (Error) Definición duplicada para: 'xxx',**

and I solved with this, I put this on VM of the Server:

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

but now I have the following error:

```
/Users/hlopez/SPRING/sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.oc4j_1.5.206.v20090812/buildfiles/oracle.10.1.3.xml:74: Deploy error: Operation failed with error:
Error creating bean with name 'analyzerConfigDAOImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/mvc/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
```

I read about this, and a lot of people typed that, this error is caused for  some .jars of hibernate,
I removed the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final, but this caused more errors,

I have these .jars on my server:

```
adf-connections.jar
adfmtl.jar
adfui.jar
​dc-adapters.jar
adfbinding.jar
​adfcm.jar
​adfm.jar
adfmweb.jar
adfshare.jar
​bc4jct.jar
​bc4jctejb.jar
​bc4jdomorcl.jar
​bc4jimdomains.jar
​bc4jmt.jar
​bc4jmtejb.jar
​collections.jar
​commons-cli-1.0.jar
jdev-cm.jar
​ojmisc.jar
​regexp.jar
​share.jar
​xmlef.jar
​xsqlserializers.jar
concurrent.jar
mdsrt.jar
ordhttp.jar
ordim.jar
```

Help please, Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a problem with different hibernates on the same server. Have you checked if there is other hibernate libs on your OracleAs aplication server?!

Comment: Can you post in your question a list of all your jars ?!